# WordPress: Add meta title if there is no title dedined

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, yoast, meta-title

I want to add a meta title in Yoast if there is no title set in the product.

To do this, I'm using the following function:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_title', 'wpseo_change_product_title' );
function wpseo_change_product_title( $title ) {
    if ( is_product() ) {
        // My function to generate the title
    }

    return $title;
}
```

But I only want to set the title if there is no title defined in the WooCommerce product.

I tried to check if `$title` is empty by wrapping the whole function in an if statement:

```
if ( empty($title)) {
    // function
}
```

But it has no effect.
Do I miss something?

I saw that the Yoast SEO title is never emtpy. Yoast adds some placeholder stuff. Maybe that's the reason that there is no way to check it?

Comment: Have you tried `if ( empty($title) && is_product()) {`

Comment: Yes, in this case the function doesn't add a title anymore. I guess because the title is never emtpy? Yoast adds some placeholder stuff. Maybe there is no way to check it?

Comment: @Cray you can't use the `$title` from the function to do this check because it's not the default title from WooCommerce. Try getting the title this way: `$title = get_the_title();` and perform the check on this. See the doc about this function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/

As a product is a normal post, this should work. If it works, I'll post an answer you can checkmark to make me happy.

Comment: Okay, but there is also always a title for the product. So I couldn't check if the Yoast title is empty

Comment: Am I correct that you want to set a title in the wpseo function in the case your product has no title by default? I'm confused..

Comment: There is an option in the product to set a SEO meta title with the Yoast plugin. I want to overwrite this title with my own function. But only if the Yoast title is empty. Now I saw that the Yoast title always has a title with placeholders. So I guess I need to delete this title from all products to check if it has a value or not

Comment: @Cray Ok I'll check this. Give me some mins.

Comment: @Cray Do you mean the SEO title in the product above the meta description? If yes, this can't be empty because if you delete it and save the product, Yoast will set this title again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221437/discussion-between-mr-jo-and-cray).

Comment: Okay, but that information helps. So I could delete all seo titles from the products and remove the defaults from the Yoast settings. After that the plugin wouldn't add a default title and it would be empty after saving.

Comment: @Cray Yes, thats possible. In this case you can do your check as expected. If you need the product name somehow, you can use the get_the_title function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you try to empty the Yoast SEO title in the product, Yoast will set the title again after saving because of the default product template setting in Yoast.

To fix this you need to delete the Yoats SEO default title for products by following this documentation from Yoast:

https://yoast.com/help/how-to-modify-default-snippet-templates-in-yoast-seo/

After that your check will be working if you delete the SEO title in each product.